# textFieldDidBeginEditing - not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My Header file

```
MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *customValue;

MyClass.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    customValue.delegate=self;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)customValue
{
    NSLog(@"custom tips value %@",customValue.text);
}
```

My NSLog is printing the message, but the `customValue.text` is not being displayed and is coming as null.

**EDIT 1**
I need to get the values that is entered in the textfiled as and when the user is enter the value

Comment: hey what you want exactly?? here begin of textfield , textfield is null , so please what u want exactly

Comment: Dude at start the text will be nil.

Comment: You must have connect delegete from XIB

Comment: Fix this question's title, because textfieldDidBeginEditing works in your question, as you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textFieldDidBeginEditing` as it name indicates , it will work when you start editing on the textField.

For accomplishing your requirement you need to use the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)e shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *substring = textField.text;
    substring = [substring stringByAppendingString:string];
    NSLog(@"Text : %@",substring);
    return YES;
}
```

**textFieldDidBeginEditing**:

> Tells the delegate that editing began for the specified text field.
>
> `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField Parameters`
>
> **textField**
>
> ```
> The text field for which an editing session began.
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method notifies the delegate that the specified text field just
>   became the first responder. You can use this method to update your
>   delegate’s state information. For example, you might use this method
>   to show overlay views that should be visible while editing.
>
> Implementation of this method by the delegate is optional.
>   Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In UITextField.h

**textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:**

> Asks the delegate if the specified text should be changed.
>
> `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`
>
> Parameters
>
> **textField**
>
> ```
> The text field containing the text.
> ```
>
> **range**
>
> ```
> The range of characters to be replaced
> ```
>
> **string**
>
> ```
> The replacement string.
> ```
>
> **Return Value**
>
> YES if the specified text range should be replaced; otherwise, NO to
>   keep the old text. Discussion
>
> The text field calls this method whenever the user types a new
>   character in the text field or deletes an existing character.
>   Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In UITextField.h

For more check [**UITextFieldDelegate**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is because `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` is called on the user **first** touch of the textField.

To get the `textField`'s text as the user changes it, connect the "Editing Changed" event to the File's Owner's IBAction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had the same problem; the reason I forgot to connect my text field's Editing Changed event to the .h file of my view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)customTipsValue shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
 replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
NSLog(@"textfield value %@",customTipsValue.text);
return YES;
}// return NO to not change text
```

Comment: This snippet is working, but it is eating one character. I have entered 123, but Log is showing me 12

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed that the method

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)customTipsValue
```

Is called when you start to edit the textField, not when you enter characters.

Check more info here:

[UITextField Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

Answer (score 0):

just set clear textfield is no when its begin to edit mode..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
       customValue.delegate=self;
       [customValue setClearsOnBeginEditing:NO];// Add this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need this [textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField%3ashouldChangeCharactersInRange%3areplacementString%3a)